# Docker volume recreates a new target path every time

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have created the following docker file

```
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian:jessie-20160831
.. 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/asmp
COPY src /usr/bin/asmp/
VOLUME /usr/bin/asmp/data
..
```

The copy actions copies a directory structure like this:

```
data
   db.sqlite3 
web
    ...
worker
    ...
```

I than just start a container, using something like this:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 asmp
```

When I do an inspect I see this:

```
 "Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "30ccc87580cd85108cb4948798612630640b5564f66de848a4e2f77db8148d3a",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/30ccc87580cd85108cb4948798612630640b5564f66de848a4e2f77db8148d3a/_data",
            "Destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "c4473031d209eb29d3f454be68325c6b1f33aa660185bf57e8abb91a56bb260e",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/c4473031d209eb29d3f454be68325c6b1f33aa660185bf57e8abb91a56bb260e/_data",
            "Destination": "/usr/bin/asmp/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
```

When I stop the container (by killing it) and than starting it again, it creates a new volume to a different directory. So I am wondering how to handle with this situation? Am I starting/stopping the container wrong? Or should I specify the volume differently? I do know that you can specify a target path, but can I (and should I ) specify this in the docker file? I rather specify the volume settings in the docker file, since the run command is already having a lot of parameters to redirect ports and devices..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify volume destination when you run container. [Read about volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems)

`docker run -p 8000:8000 --volume=<path_on_host>:/usr/bin/asmp/data asmp`

Comment: What is than the point of defining it in the dockerfile if you still have to define it in the run command?

Comment: unfortunately you can't define it into Dockerfile. Let me show you [Dockerfile volume reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume) 
VOLUME expect only one argument this may be a string or array of string, which contains mount points inside container.

Comment: Lets look at [docker-compose tool](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). It allow you write config file when you can define all variables for container running.

Comment: Thanks, will look into your informatie. But what is the point of defining it in the dockerfile?

Comment: In Dockerfile you specify which directories must contains information **outside** of container independently how is you running container e.g. logs, media files. Dockerfile defines the contract (inerface) of container. When you run container you only specify **where exactly** this information will be stored. 
Probably Volume directive can be omitted in dockerfile. Docker sometimes is strange

Comment: You can't define a specific host directory in the Dockerfile but you can specify a volume and it should be preserved across docker runs. Docker then manages the host location i.e. the long /var/lib/docker... paths that Maarten has above.  However, it is not reusing them across docker runs which does beg the question what is the purpose of the VOLUME command in a dockerfile.  I have the same problem as Maarten and completely agree with him that it should work.